# How can LEFT JOIN with UNION?

Tags: sql

There are 2 same structure TABLE : Product01 and Product02.
I use UNION to merge two TABLE and select the row with %LIKE%. However LIKE '%"A1234"%' change , always select same row.The following is sql code.

```
SELECT product_id
FROM Product01
UNION
SELECT product_id
FROM Product02
WHERE product_code LIKE '%"A1234"%'
ORDER BY product_id ASC
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance,

Comment: Also, which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the where for both selects:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM Product01
WHERE product_code LIKE '%"A1234"%'
UNION
SELECT product_id
FROM Product02
WHERE product_code LIKE '%"A1234"%'
```

You could also rewrite the query so the where applies to the result of the union:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT product_id, product_code
FROM Product01
UNION
SELECT product_id, product_code
FROM Product02)
SELECT product_id 
from x 
WHERE product_code LIKE '%"A1234"%'
ORDER BY product_id ASC
```